# Laravel Queued Job with a backoff not working on SQS

Tags: laravel, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I've been trying to automatically retry a failed job with a backoff set.
While this is working fine with RabbitMQ locally, I can't seem to get it to work on AWS SQS.
By adding logging I could confirm the job is properly retried following the `$tries` property, but the `$backoff` seems to be ignored completely. So it is basically retrying 3 times one after another.
For full disclosure, I'm working with SQS and Elastic Beanstalk (worker environment in this case)

```
class FailingJob extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable;
    use InteractsWithQueue;
    use Queueable;
    use SerializesModels;

    public int $tries = 3;
    public int $backoff = 30; // Wait 30 seconds before retrying

    public function handle()
    {
        throw new \Exception('attemt #'. $this->attempts());
    }
}
```

I tried:

- updating aws/aws-sdk-php to the latest version (v3.263.0)
- updating my Laravel 9 version to the latest version (v9.52.5)
- increasing the $backoff to 30000 (going after a hunch that their might be a second vs mili-second issue)

Lot's more shots in the dark were made during testing, but decided to see if someone here has any idea what is going on before continuing my trial and error approach

Comment: I'm having the same issue but on localhost running mysql. The $backoff property seems to be ignored completely

Comment: I realized my issue was testing with too many jobs in the queue. I would push 100 jobs onto the queue at once. And if a job fails it seems to go to the BACK of the queue, so the next job is handled right away. And by the time 100 jobs cycled, the $backoff time already passed. If I only push 3 jobs onto the queue it's easier to see $backoff time in action